# Remove attribute from all MongoDB documents using Python and PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In my MongoDB, a bunch of these documents exist:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5341eaae6e59875a9c80fa68"),
  "parent" : {
      "tokeep" : 0,
      "toremove" : 0
  }
}
```

I want to remove the `parent.toremove` attribute in every single one.

Using the MongoDB shell, I can accomplish this using:

```
db.collection.update({},{$unset: {'parent.toremove':1}},false,true)
```

**But how do I do this within Python?**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
mongo = PyMongo(app)
mongo.db.collection.update({},{$unset: {'parent.toremove':1}},false,true)
```

returns the following error:

```
  File "myprogram.py", line 46
mongo.db.collection.update({},{$unset: {'parent.toremove':1}},false,true)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put quotes around `$unset`, name the parameter you're including (`multi`) and use the correct syntax for true:

```
mongo.db.collection.update({}, {'$unset': {'parent.toremove':1}}, multi=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found weird to have to attach an arbitrary value for the field to remove, such as a small number (1), an empty string (''), etc, but it's really mentioned in MongoDB doc, with sample in JavaScript:

> $unset
>
> The $unset operator deletes a particular field. Consider the following syntax:
>
> { $unset: { field1: "", ... } }
>
> The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact
>   the operation.

For Python/PyMongo, I'd like to put a value `None`:

```
{'$unset': {'field1': None}}
```

So, for OP's question, it would be:

```
mongo.db.collection.update({}, {'$unset': {'parent.toremove': None}}, multi=True)
```

Comment: how about removing multiple fields with pymong?